# Vlook up style forumla but range is 2 cells

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Here is a sample sheet with no formulas yet. I want something to return a 1 based on B and C

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-DWYgyrOm3JryO6uq_ZfJzNGcsWFfBBFYcSxjF4NKXI/edit?usp=sharing

Eg1 if B2=Classic Espresso Blend and C2=contains the word "medium" the result is a 1 in F2

Eg2 ( slightly more complex ) if B21=Mixed Medium Subscription and C21 contains "espresso and filter" return a 1 in both H21 and L21. Other possibilities could be "espresso and blend" and "filter and blend" and they would correspond to the 225 columns

This will allow me to tally up at the bottom of each column what's needed

Hope this makes sense

I'm not very experienced. I've used Vlookup for other things in the past but this has a more complex range and I can't get Vlookup to work for this

Comment: Please post the code you've tried already and what's wrong with it - see [ask] and [mre] for details.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this formula in cell D2; it auto applies to whole columns of D2:O

```
=MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(B2:B),COUNTA(D1:O1),LAMBDA(r,c,IF(REGEXMATCH(LAMBDA(ax,bx,IFS(REGEXMATCH(ax,"Mixed")*REGEXMATCH(INDEX(C2:C,r),"Blend")*REGEXMATCH(INDEX(C2:C,r),"Filter"),"BLEND-"&bx&"|FILTER-"&bx,REGEXMATCH(ax,"Mixed")*NOT(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(C2:C,r),"Blend"))*REGEXMATCH(INDEX(C2:C,r),"Filter"),"ESP-"&bx&"|FILTER-"&bx,REGEXMATCH(ax,"Mixed")*NOT(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(C2:C,r),"Filter")),"BLEND-"&bx&"|ESP-"&bx,LEN(ax),SUBSTITUTE(ax&"-"&bx,"Espresso","ESP")))(regexextract(INDEX(B2:B,r),"([^\s]*?) Subscription"),IFNA(SWITCH(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(C2:C,r),"Small|Medium|Large"),"Small",250,"Medium",450,"Large",900),SWITCH(REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(B2:B,r),"Medium|Large"),"Medium",225,"Large",450))),"(?i)"&INDEX(D1:O1,,c)),1,)))
```

you may need to test this extensively for 'Mixed' subscription scenarios.
Currently its tested for 3 scenarios of mix-match (***BLEND+FILTER, ESP+FILTER, BLEND+ESP***) as you can see in rows 21-24 of the screenshot

-

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for this!!!! wow.

I dont really understand what you've done here but i am testing it and so far its great. Will test further and give some feedback

Comment: This has been working well so far thank you! I would love to add some other items to it but have no idea where to start. 

I'd like to add in "Decaf" columns and they would operate the same as the filter, espresso and blend columns. (225, 250, 450 and 900)

I'd like to add in "capsule" columns too. There would only be 2 columns - medium and large

and lastly theres a product i have called "FOMO subscription" similar to the mixed subscription and it equals 1 x filter-250 + 1 x espresso-250 + 1 x blend-250

If you can help i'd be so grateful!  @rockinfreakshow

Comment: are you able to explain the formula a little? or let me know how to add in more attributes like mentioned above in the comment.

not sure if tagging you is working?